# Reactjs. I have an arrow key navigation problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to do xmb (psp/ps3) menu in react and i have a problem. The problem is that items scroll through the next item. For example: *Item 1 scrolls to Item 3 (Item 2 is skipped although item 2 should come after 1 item)* and in back *From Item 3 to 1*. How Can i fix it?

**The demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/relaxed-cohen-05tvt6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark**

I tried some ways

```
      $(".container").on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.which === arrowKeys.left) {
          _position = --_position / _length;
        }

        if (e.which === arrowKeys.right) {
          _position = ++_position / _length;
        }

        move();
      });
```

```
      $(".container").on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.which === arrowKeys.left) {
          _position = (1-_position) % _length;
        }

        if (e.which === arrowKeys.right) {
          _position = (1-_position) % _length;
        }

        move();
      });
```

```
      $(".container").on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.which === arrowKeys.left) {
          _position = --_position % (_length-1);
        }

        if (e.which === arrowKeys.right) {
          _position = ++_position % (_length-1);
        }

        move();
      });
```

And i edited in HTML

```
          <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="item" tabIndex="1">
            item 1
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="3">
            item 2
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="2">
            item 3
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="5">
            item 4
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="4">
            item 5
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="7">
            item 6
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="6">
            item 7
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="9">
            item 8
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="8">
            item 9
          </div>
          <div class="item" tabIndex="10">
            item 10
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

But none of this ways worked. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using [`<StrictMode>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) in the index.js file.

> To help surface these issues, React 18 introduces a new development-only check to Strict Mode. This new check will automatically **unmount and remount** every component, whenever a component mounts for the first time, restoring the previous state on the second mount.

This will re-run some lifecycle methods (*like `componentDidMount`*) and so it will add your key handler twice.

---

You could ofcource make your code more defensive and remove all the global event handlers once the component is unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

I think using React instead of Jquery to listen to events is the best way.

> These codes only demo how to refactor the keydown event.

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-framework-jsbrx2?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import "./style.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  _position = 1;
  _length = 0;
  arrowKeys = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };

  componentDidMount() {
    const componentRef = this;
    (function () {
      var _items = $(".container").find(".item");
      componentRef._length = _items.length;

      $(".container").on("focus", ".item", function () {
        componentRef._position = $(this).index();
      });

      $(".container").on("click", ".item", function () {
        componentRef.move();
      });
    })();
  }

  move() {
    $(".container").find(".item").get(this._position).focus();
    $(".wrapper").css("transform", function (a, b) {
      var left = a - 3 * this._position + "%";
      return "translate3d(" + left + ",0,0)";
    });
  }

  customKeydown = (e) => {
    if (e.which === this.arrowKeys.left) {
      this._position = --this._position % this._length;
    }

    if (e.which === this.arrowKeys.right) {
      this._position = ++this._position % this._length;
    }

    this.move();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="container" onKeyDown={this.customKeydown}>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="1">
            item 1
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="2">
            item 2
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="3">
            item 3
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="4">
            item 4
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="5">
            item 5
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="6">
            item 6
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="7">
            item 7
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="8">
            item 8
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="9">
            item 9
          </div>
          <div className="item" tabIndex="10">
            item 10
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```